# how to add key and value to array that is mongodb find result (added key/value gets lost)

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

This must be a standard Javascript problem, but my searches here did not turn up any results that were applicable to me.

I am querying a mongodb database and want to add key/values to the objects in the result array through the enrichJSON function.

The MongoBooks.find returns some documents in an Array docs. Probably enrichJSON is a bad name, it should be something like enrichArray, it is arbitrary anyway.

```
function enrichJSON(jsonobj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.length; i++) {
        jsonobj[i].myparam = "something meaningful";
    }
    return jsonobj;
}

MongoBooks.find(mongoquery, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var step1 = docs;
    var step2 = enrichJSON(step1);
    console.log("step1:" + step1);
    console.log("step2:" + step2);
  });
```

The step2 console output is missing the myparam output. Same goes if I try

```
jsonobj[i]["myparam"] = "abctest";
```

in the enrichJSON.

I am getting

```
step1: {[{"title":"good book"}]}
step2: {[{"title":"good book"}]}
```

but would like to get

```
step2: {[{"title":"good book", "myparam":"something meaningful"}]}
```

Edit to give an actual (stripped down) example of my result (I edited to make it simpler but probably mixed up the brackets):

```
step2:{ _id: 5474e8a35e79556ced436700,
  isbn10: '0370303466',
  author: 'Graham Greene',
  lang: 'eng',
  title: 'Travels with my aunt'
  }
```

I am still missing what I added (myparam).

Comment: `{[{"title":"good book"}]}` isn't a valid JS or JSON object. There's no property mapped to that array.

Comment: I made that up since the object actually has many more properties. So actually, in my case I sent a query that only responds with one object. I will edit original post to give proper formatted example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken response.

```
{[{"title":"good book"}]}
```

should be something like this :

```
{'data' : [{"title":"good book"}]}
```

Then your enrich function would look like this :

```
function enrichJSON(jsonobj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.data.length; i++) {
        jsonobj.data[i].myparam = "something meaningful";
    }
    return jsonobj;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for given broken example. The edited/updated example should give the correct format. In case of multiple book results (the normal case), the output is just several objects, separated by comma, like {_id:'1',title:'abc'},{id:'2',title:'def'},{_id:'3',title:'abc2'}

Comment: Ok, it is somehow a property on a subobject.. it should be

    jsonobj[i]._doc.myparam = "abctest";

then it also shows up in result

Comment: Your new example does not show an array, so it will not loop over an object with a for loop since the object has no "length" property.

Comment: I was getting confused, too - with the find() method I always expect an array, that is also why I created the samples wrongly first (they were not real outputs).
Anyway, since your answer helped me find the solution, I will accept it. (I just needed to add _doc - see above.)
Still working on figuring out javascript and its peculiarities..